# How do you add a section to your channel and then add single videos to it?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel

This is driving me crazy.

I am trying to add a section to my channel homepage where I can then add individual videos I have uploaded but the only options I have are to add playlists, liked videos, posted videos, etc.

Is this even possible?  I've seen it on other channels so I am confused...or doing something wrong.

Comment: What stops you from creating a playlist with the videos you want to feature and then using the "single playlist" option?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a [new playlist](https://www.youtube.com/view_all_playlists) with whatever videos you want listed on your channel page.

[image: Playlist of videos]

2. Go to your channel page, scroll to the bottom, and click the **Add a section** button

[image: Add a section button]

3. Select **Single playlist** for content, **My Playlists** for choose a playlist, and select your newly created playlist.

[image: Section details]

4. Preview your new section below, and click **Done** to add it to your channel

[image: Section preview]